# How to change the elements in all the odd columns of the matrix?

Tags: matlab

I need to write a function that "If x = 3" the function will set the elements in all the odd columns of the matrix to M (when M is the number of elements in the matrix).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = [3 5 2;
     4 7 1];

A(:,1:2:end)=numel(A);
```

[Please read this link](http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html), so you can do it yourself next time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
a = rand(7, 3)
m = 5 % your definition of m

0.6557    0.3922    0.0971
0.0357    0.6555    0.8235
0.8491    0.1712    0.6948
0.9340    0.7060    0.3171
0.6787    0.0318    0.9502
0.7577    0.2769    0.0344
0.7431    0.0462    0.4387

a(1:2:size(a,1),:) = m

5.0000    5.0000    5.0000
0.0357    0.6555    0.8235
5.0000    5.0000    5.0000
0.9340    0.7060    0.3171
5.0000    5.0000    5.0000
0.7577    0.2769    0.0344
5.0000    5.0000    5.0000
```

Just need to get the odd indices with `1:2:end`.

Comment: Not really. I mean, if my matrix is 
(3 5 2;
4 7 1)
So there are 6 elements in the matrix, and I need to change the numbers in the odd columns to 6
Like this:
(6 5 6;
6 7 6)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3075653 Oops! Seems I got the `rows` ha!